# WPF UserControl Container C# VS 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have a problem because y want to create a UserControl that can have a functionality as a container.

I used the link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813450/en-us?fr=1

but i suposed that this part don't work for WPF 4.0:

**[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))]** 
public class UserControl1 : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{

```
  ...
```

}

Please Help Me¡¡¡¡¡

Answer (score 0):

You are using Forms UserControl...

Start using WPF [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) instead and all will be well!

```
public class UserControl1 : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
```